# Example of discontinuity of position operator $X\colon f(x) \mapsto xf(x)$ for $f(x) \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

It is well known that continuous linear operators are bounded and vice versa. It is also well known that the [position operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_operator) (which I shall call $X$) causes many headaches in quantum mechanics due to its unboundedness, which results in the construction of rigged Hilbert spaces and so on.

I know that
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x}, & x \geq 1\\ 0, & x < 1\end{cases}$$
can be used as an example for a function $ f(x) \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ that demonstrates the unboundedness of $X$. However, I would be interested in an example that explicitly shows the/a *discontinuity* of $X$.

By linearity, it should even be possible (for example) to find a sequence that converges to the everywhere zero function where the $X$ operator is discontinuous, however, after playing around with a few Gaussian function sequences and trying to look up some canonical example, I couldn't come up with such a case. What would an example be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ is unbounded, then there exists some sequence $(f_n)$ such that $\|X(f_n)\| \to \infty$ but $\|f_n\| \le 1$. Let $g_n = f_n / \|X(f_n)\|$. Then
$$0 \le \|g_n\| = \frac{\|f_n\|}{\|X(f_n)\|} \le \frac{1}{\|X(f_n)\|} \to 0.$$
Thus, $g_n \to 0$, but
$$\|X(g_n)\| = \frac{\|X(f_n)\|}{\|X(f_n)\|} = 1,$$
and hence $X(g_n)$ does not converge to $0$. This provides your counterexample.

In this situation, $X$ is not just discontinuous at $0$, but discontinuous **everywhere**. Simply shift this sequence by any $f_0$, and you'll get a sequence $g_n \to f_0$, but $X(g_n) \not\to X(f_0)$.

Comment: Very nice. A concrete example following your schema could be $g_n = \sqrt{\frac{2}{n}} x^{-\left(\frac{3}{2} + \frac{1}{n}\right)}$.

Comment: ... for $x \geq 1$, $0$ else; as above. I forgot that part.